# Why am I getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" from GetDirectoryEntry()?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I have some strange error.

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://11.111.111.11", "user", "1");

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
{
    PageSize = int.MaxValue,
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + txt + "*))"
};

SearchResultCollection resultCollection = searcher.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult result in resultCollection)
{
    if (result != null)
    {
        users.Add(new ObjectTest(
        result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value as string,
        result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value as string,
        result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value as string,
        result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value as string));
    }
}

directoryEntry.Close();
```

When I search some users I get collection of them and after that use them in foreach.
For example: I type user and get collection with 5 users, after that I fill my array.

But some times I get collection with users that give me error here:

For example I type test and I know that I have user "test" and I see my collection with correct count, but after result.GetDirectoryEntry() I get exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can't find nothing similar on site.

Note:
Collection has normal count of objects, and SearchResult is not null it has normal Path!
Thank you!

Comment: [What is NullReference and how do I fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Note:
Collection has normal count of objects, and SearchResult is not null it has normal Path!

Comment: Could you check if the "result.GetDirectoryEntry()" is not null too? Same question about "Properties[]".

Comment: So do I understand correctly that it's the `.Value` that's throwing the exception?

Comment: YES! result is not null.
I get error if I write
result.GetDirectoryEntry()

Comment: Not value:
this string gives me error 
result.GetDirectoryEntry()

Comment: @user1711993, that doesn't make sense.  If you've tested `result` already (in your `if` test), `result` cannot be null.  It has to be something farther along in the code.

Comment: I guess *maybe* `GetDirectoryEntry` itself is throwing a `NullReferenceException` from its own code, but that seems highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my comment, answer-ified:

Check the results of the `Properties` getters; presumably one of them is returning null, and that's where your `NullReferenceException` is coming from (when you try to get a null property's `Value`).

**Edit:** Couldn't delete the answer, but according to @baldpate in the comments, `PropertyCollection.Item[string]` will never return null, so the above is not the explanation for the `NullReferenceException`.  In any case, the strategy for finding the source of the exception is:

1. Put each method call on its own line and store the result in a variable.
2. Step through your code a line at a time, testing outputs until you find the one that's null.

Comment: The DirectoryEntry.Properties and PropertyCollection.Item[string] will never return null.

Comment: @baldpate, from the OP's comments it appears that `PropertyCollection.Item[string]` can indeed return null.  I personally wouldn't know.

Comment: From reflector `PropertyCollection.Item[string]` will always return a `PropertyValueCollection` instance, even the given attribute name is sth like "@#$%^".

Comment: Thank you again!! I will follow your advice